# phonegap and cordova not opening link in app browser

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap-desktop-app

I am new to PhoneGap and Cordova, I am trying to create a wrapper application script for my website.

However the problem I am getting is that, when I build the app using PhoneGap cloud and click on a link on an external link in the page it opens the link in Chrome and not the native browser, do I need to install anything? Like a plugin or something?

I have checked that the plugins are in the project that PhoneGap desktop app created for me, however do I need to copy them in to the `www` folder?

```
/plugins/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

My code is simple and I am trying a few different methods to open it in the native browser:

```
<div id="deviceready" class="blink">
    <h1>Test App</h1>
    <a href='#' onclick='navigator.app.loadUrl("http://www.tutorialspoint.com/", {openExternal : false});'/>Test</a><br/>
    <a href='#' onclick="navigator.app.loadUrl('http://www.tutorialspoint.com/', { openExternal:true });">Link</a><br/>
    <a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.tutorialspoint.com/', '_system');">system</a><br/>
    <a href='http://www.tutorialspoint.com/'/>Google</a><br/>
    <a href='newpage.html'/>newpage</a><br/>
</div>
```

Comment: check whitelist plugin

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/

Comment: @AbdouTelb thanks for the reply i have already done that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to initialize the plugin like so:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
}
```

This is taken from the https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/

> _blank: Opens in the InAppBrowser.
>
> _system: Opens in the system's web browser.

Therefor you need to change :

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.tutorialspoint.com/', '_system');">system</a><br/>
```

To this :

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.tutorialspoint.com/', '_blank', 'location=yes');">system</a><br/>
```

Comment: Hi Jesper, Thanks for the comment, i have just tried your suggestion and that still opens the link in chrome

Comment: @ffmsingh - Did you initialize the InAppBrowser? See updated solution.

Comment: @ffmsingh - I need to see your javascript code then.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i have fixed this now :) I had my javascript in the wrong place!, i put it at the bottom of the the index.js but when i move it to the bottom of the index.html it works.